Как с помощью ардуино передать приложение на пк?
Я недавно купил arduino pro micro. Хочу сейчас сделать badusb (В целях обучения). Мне нужно как-то передать файл на пк жертвы, но я не знаю как это сделать. Можно ли как-то на пк под управлением windows 10 создать бинарник или exe с заранее записанным в ардуино содержимым? Возможно, это можно сделать с помощью кодировки исполняемого файла в base64 и последующей декодировкой его уже на машине жертвы? Я хочу это сделать не скачивая его откуда-либо, а создавая локально. Если где-то ошибся в технической части, извиняюсь, я еще не сильно изучил эту тему.
p.s. Я пытался делать так:
echo "exe, декодированный в base64">>test123.txt & certutil -encode test123.txt out.exe

Но, к сожалению, exe не запускался:

Если выполнить в cmd, то получаю:

Хотя до перекодировки этот же файл запускался без каких-либо проблем. Прошу помощи у более умных людей.

Нет, нельзя! Pro Micro не имеет USB интерфейса. Доступ к USB идет через микросхему USB-UART конвертер.
Оригинальная Arduino имеет вторую микросхему ATmega16u2 - которая имеет USB интерфейс и конвертирует USB в UART. Перепрошить в флешку надо именно ее, но ее объем памяти настолько ничтожно мал, что в нее ни одна 32х битная программа не уместится.
Вторая загвоздка, если ты упоришь прошивку в ATmega16u2 - ты превратишь всю плату в кирпич.
Китайские Ардуино - в качестве UART конвертера используют чип - ch340, они сами по себе не программируемые. По факту это обычный USB в UART.
Если не сэкономил и купил оригинал, то перепрошей 16u2 на USBFlash и используй ATmega328p как память.
PS: Писать вирусы очень плохо.
PSS: У 328й всего 32Кб памяти, тебе придется очень постараться что-бы твоя программа уместилась туда.


Спасибо, понял!
